# Passing parameters between two different web applications

Tags: asp.net, parameters

I have two different web application in which i have logged in one of them.Now I want to pass those login credentials to the second web application and to do log in without a click.

what will be the secure and convenient way to do this. And what important modifications are needed on two simple login pages. Both of the project are being handled by the same database.

any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: How about Exposing an end point from second application and passing log in credentials to that end point and log in accordingly. I am beginner. Just throwing the ideas

Comment: Thanks @Unbreakable the problem is both of the apps belongs to different solutions so m getting confused how to pass and how to receive the credentials.

Comment: How about create a WebApi?

Comment: You can create a web api and its end point can be accessed from other app/solution.

Comment: Yup that could work...Let me try.

Comment: @Unbreakable thanks man that worked.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer. Accept kar lena! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WebApi` for any third party to get access to your application. `WebApi` works as an end point. Here is the basic sample/syntax.

```
 // GET /api/customers
    public IHttpActionResult GetCustomers()
    {
        var customerDtos = _context.Customers
            .Include(c => c.MembershipType)
            .ToList()
            .Select(Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerDto>);
        return Ok(customerDtos);
    }
```

For POST

```
 // POST /api/customers
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateCustomer(CustomerDto customerDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest();

        var customer = Mapper.Map<CustomerDto, Customer>(customerDto);
        _context.Customers.Add(customer);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        customerDto.Id = customer.Id;

        return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + customer.Id), customerDto);
    }
```

In order to check if your api end point is working properly, You can download `Chrome Extension "ARC" - Advanced Rest Client`. Using this you can `test` the API end point and it's output. You do no need a third party full fledged app to test the end point.